# Не могу скопировать файлы через терминал Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Необходимо скопировать все найденные файлы имеющие расширение .log из директории /var в созданную ранее директорию /logs_1, написал такую команду: "find /var -name "*log" -a -type f -exec cp {} /home/test_1/ 2>/dev/null", но она не срабатывает, хотя вроде бы как выполняется, в чём может быть проблема? (после выполнения директория как была пустая, таковой она и остается)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вообще-то, файлы логов обычно хранятся в каталоге */var/log/*/ Покажите вывод команды ls /var | grep log

Comment: https://prnt.sc/-btvXmkbMCxg

Comment: Хорошо. А теперь такая команда: *cat /var/log*  Если не получится, попробуйте так: *sudo cat /var/log*